# Having trouble with mysql Select Query

Tags: php, mysql, select, mysqli

I have a table named `batch`

```
batch_id      unit_size       product_id
2             100000          c001
3             30000           t008
```

another table named `batch_process`

```
batch_id      process_id      status
2             100000          0
2             100000          1
2             100000          2
2             100000          1
3             30000           2
3             30000           2
3             30000           2
3             30000           2
```

Now I want to get output `3` AS `batch_id` form `batch` table because in `batch_process` table all `process_id` status is `2` for `batch_id = 3`

How can I select it.

Comment: not clear! can you show a sample output?

Comment: Something like this: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/aecc39/2 ?

Answer (score 0):

This query may help you

```
SELECT batch1.batch_id,batch_process1.process_id 
FROM batch_process AS batch_process1,
batch AS batch1
WHERE batch1.batch_id = batch_process1.batch_id 
AND batch_process1.status=2
```

Answer (score 0):

If u just want to select batch_id whose status is 2 then you can just write:

```
select distinct batch_id from batch_process where status=2
```

but if u want to query info from batch table not only the batch_id, you can write:

```
SELECT batch.batch_id,
       batch.unit_size,
       batch.product_id
LEFT JOIN batch_process ON batch.batch_id=batch_process.batch_id
WHERE batch_process.status=2
```